# time data does not match format Error in Python

Tags: python, django

This should be simple but I can't get I have a `datetime` value that I convert to string and store in *last_time*.

I need to convert it back to `datetime` object so that I can use it to fetch more data from my model but it

`raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %` *I am also wondering why this error doesn't have a closing parenthesis*.

and I get

`ValueError: time data '2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Saved your timestamp with - between year, month and day and while converting it back to time you are saying that i am using /. I tested your timestamp with  format **"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"** and it works.

```
import time
print time.strptime("2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```